# Cucumber doesn't work but rake cucumber does

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, rake

```
Jonathans-MacBook-Air-2:hw3-rottenpotatoes Jonathan$ cucumber
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.37)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
You have already activated activesupport 4.0.0, but your Gemfile requires activesupport 3.2.14. Using bundle exec may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
/Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:33:in `block in setup'
/Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
/Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
/Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7:in `'
```

But it seems like I have the right rails version in this directory.

```
Jonathans-MacBook-Air-2:hw3-rottenpotatoes Jonathan$ rails --version
Rails 3.2.14
```

I'm kind of new to ruby and am confused as to why "rake cucumber" works but "cucumber" doesn't in the terminal.
I don't know how ruby and gems are set up but I have a hunch is that somehow in my working directory, ruby is told to use rails 3.2.14 but the command "cucumber" is only detecting activtesupport 4.0.0 (which I believe is tied to rails)

Thanks so much!

Comment: can you show your gemfile?

Comment: have you tried "bundle exec cucumber" ?  It looks like you have rake installed outside your gemfile and that's being picked up.  But you don't have cucumber installed outside your gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

`cucumber` is a binstub, while `rake cucumber` is a rake task that executes the library.

Try `bundle install -—binstubs` first, then try `cucumber`.

Perhaps the binstub is somehow out of date?

If that doesn't work, just kill the binstubs by deleting the `project/bin` dir, and rerun `bundle install -—binstubs`

Comment: `cucumber` command _is a_ binstub, located in `bin/cucumber`.

Comment: not in a Rails 3 project it isn't, unless you specifically add it as one, which I presume the user has not done.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple versions of Rails installed and cucumber doesn't know which to use, so it's trying to load both and erroring out.

To use the one specified in your Gemfile, specify `bundle exec` before all commands, eg. `bundle exec cucumber`.